# $X_H$ compact $\Rightarrow X$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a topological space with equivalence relation $\sim$ defined as: $x \sim y$ if for any $Y$ that is a Hausdorff space and any continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ we have that $f(x) = f(y)$. $X/\sim$ is called the largest Hausdorff quotient of $X$ if we equip it with the quotient topology and if we consider the canonical projection map $\pi_H: X \rightarrow X_H$.

I was able to prove that if $X$ is compact then $X_H$ has to be compact as well.

I have been told that the converse statement does not hold. Are there any counterexamples that could show that this statement is false?

Comment: The  quotient topology on $X/\sim$ is defined ro be the strongest topology such that the quotient map is continuous. The continuous image of a compact space is compact. So of course if $X$ is compact then $X_H$ is compact.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, yes I was able to prove this as I said in the post! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a closed interval with infinitely many copies of the origin.

Take the interval $([-3,3], \tau)$, with a base $B$ for the usual topology, and add to the set $[-3,3]$ infinitely many copies of $0$: $\{(0, n) : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. To the base $B$, add in copies of a neighbourhood base of $0$ for each copy of $0$. For example, one new base for this topology is $B$ union the set of all sets of the form $(-r, r) - \{0\}\cup \{(0,n)\}$ (where $r$ is a positive real, and $n$ natural).

It's clear from the way the neighborhoods of the copies of the origin are defined that any continuous map to a Hausdorff space must send all the origins to the same point.

You can get an open cover of the line with infinite origins that has no finite subcover as follows:
Let your open cover contain $[-3, -1)$, $(1, 3]$, $(-2,2)$, and every open set of the form $(-2, 2) - \{0\}\cup \{(0,n)\}$.

---

EDIT:
To be very explicit, we create a new topological space $(X, \tau)$.
Let $X = [-3,3] \cup \{(0, n) : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ (you can imagine these points as being `borrowed' from $\mathbb{R}^2$, the point is just that they are new points not usually on the interval $[-3,3]$).

We let $\tau$ contain every open set that belongs to the normal Euclidean topology on $[-3,3]$. We *also* let $\tau$ contain every set of the form $(-r, r) - \{0\}\cup \{(0,n)\}$, where $r$ is real, and $n$ is natural.
AND we let $\tau$ contain any arbitrary union or countable intersection of any kind of set mentioned so far.

Comment: (apologies, made a very dumb mistake on original answer - replace $\mathbb{R}$ with any big enough closed interval about $0$).

Comment: Looks great! I think I found a different example, would you mind having a look? Take $X = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, + \infty)$ with the Euclidean topology, $Y = \{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Then $Y$ is trivially Hausdorff. Also consider the map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ that send all the positive numbers to $1$ and the negative numbers to $0$. Then $f$ is continuous. So we have $X/ \sim = \{[1],[-1]\}$, which is compact, but $X$ is definitely not.

Comment: @Geigercounter If $X$ is Hausdorff, then $X_H = X$.

Comment: @Geigercounter You cannot fix a single choice of $Y$. The relation $\sim$ only identifies two points when they are mapped together by *every* function from $X$ into *any* Hausdorff space.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez but if the theorem fails for a single choice of $Y$, can we not say that the theorem does not hold?

Comment: @Geigercounter, The problem here is you cannot say that $\sim$ identifies all of $(-\infty, 0)$ together and all of $(0, \infty)$ together, which is what you are claiming. You can separate any two points you like in $X$ with *some* map to *some* Compact Hausdorff space (for example, try different maps into the space $Y = [-2,-1]\cup [1,2]$). Basically: $X/\sim$ is not what you claim it is. In fact, $X/\sim \simeq X$! You need to think of a space $X$ where you *have* to merge points, *no matter what space $Y$ you map into*

Comment: @Geigercounter As I said above, if $X$ is Hausdorff (which is the case for example), then $X_H = X$. To see this, note that $id_X : X \to X$ is a continuous map to a Hausdorff space; this shows that $x \sim y$ implies $x = id_X(x) = id_X(y) = y$.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez I am a bit confused on your notation of the copies of the origin. Are these points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? Either way could you add some more clarification? Thanks! EDIT: also another question: does the interval $[-3,3]$ have to be closed?

Comment: Also I don't really understand what you mean by "To the base B, add in copies of a neighbourhood base of 0 for each copy of 0." and the following example

Comment: @Geigercounter Yes, the interval $I$ must be closed, otherwise $I/\sim$ won't be compact. I've added a paragraph at the end explaining how the topology is constructed in more detail.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez thanks!!

Comment: @Geigercounter You should make a separate question for that if you are unsure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441419/proving-x-sim-is-compact

Answer (score 0):

Let $X =\mathbb N$ with open sets $\emptyset, X$ and $U_n = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. This space is non-compact (since $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$  is an open cover of $X$ which has no finite subcover). We show that $n \sim 1$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. This implies that $X_H$ is a one-point space (which is compact).

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a map to a Hausdorff space $Y$. Assume that $f(n) \ne f(1)$. Then there are disjoint open neigborhoods $U$ of $f(n)$ and $V$ of $f(1)$. Then $U' = f^{-1}(U)$ is an non-empty  open subset of $X$ such that $1 \notin U'$, thus $U \ne X$. We conclude that $U' = U_m$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$. But $1 \in U_m = U'$, a contradiction.