# Proving $X/{\sim}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

I got a good answer to this question yesterday: [$X_H$ compact $\Rightarrow X$ compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440393/x-h-compact-rightarrow-x-compact). However, I still was wondering how to prove that $X/{\sim}$ is compact in the example written in the accepted answer. I see how $X$ is not compact and how the infinite copies of the origin are all mapped to the same point, but I don't see why in this example $X_H$ is compact.

I was advised to make a new post for this in the comments.

My apologies for not posting the context, I am in a rush.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I want to find a counterexample where $X_H$ is compact but $X$ isn't. In the accepted answer I can't seem to figure out why $X_H$ is compact

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I don't seem to understand...

Comment: My bad. I believe the space $X_{H}$ will be $[-3,3]$ so it's compact

Comment: @aldodecristo no worries. Why will the space be $[-3,3]$?

Comment: Well you have that $(-3,3]$ is dense  in $X$ so any two maps from $X\rightarrow Y$ with $Y$ hausdorff that agree on $(-3,3]$ will be equal. This uses the fact that any two continuous functions into a Hausdorff space coincide on a closed set.

Comment: @aldodecristo I'm still confused. Don't we have to find a finite open subcover?

Comment: You want to prove that $X_H=[-3,3]$ to do that you need to prove that every continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ with Y Hausdorff then all the "zeroes" get sent to the same point. What do you need a subcover for? If needed I will make an answer with all the dettails

Comment: @aldodecristo to prove that is is compact. But I see that it is trivial that $[-3,3]$ is compact, so your statement should suffice. Could elaborate a little more?

Comment: I mean that closed intervals are compact is not as trivial as you would think but yeah the compactness of $[-3,3]$ is something you ought to have seen in any introductory topology course

Comment: @aldodecristo I was able to prove that all the origins get sent to one point in $X_H$ for those $Y$ and $f$ but I still can't see why it's compact... or rather why $X_H = [-3,3]$

Comment: Do you know the fact that given $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous maps and $Y$ is Hausdorff then the set $\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}$ or the set on which the two functions coincide is closed? You also have that given the same $f$ and $g$ if they coincide on $S$ they must also coincide on $\bar{S}$ (the closure)

Comment: I recall proving this before yes

Comment: So any two functions that coincide on $(-3,3]\subseteq X$ must coincide on $X$ since it's the closure. Now assume $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if $f$ sends one of the zeroes to $y\in Y$ then there is a $g$ that sends all the zeroes into $y$ and coincides with $f$ on $(-3,3]$. Does this make sense?

Comment: You say you see why all the $0$s are equivalent. Do you also see why all non-zero points are equivalent to themselves and nothing else? So as a set $X_H$ is $[-3,3]$. But the projection $\pi_H$ from the base space $X$ into a quotient space is not only continuous, but also open. The quotient topology is effectively defined by that requirement. The basic open sets of $X$ are open sets of $[-3,3]$ with $0$ replaced by one of the $(0,n)$. The projection of that under $\pi_H$ is the unadjusted open set it was built from. Thus every open set of $[-3,3]$ is open in $X_H$ and vice versa.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair thanks for the explanation! I think that I understand it now more or less :)